# Logging only exceptions rather than all kinds of logs

Tags: log4net, log4net-configuration, log4net-appender

I am using log4net for logging in a database. It is logging everything but I want to log only exceptions. 
I'm using

```
<level value="ALL"/>
```

How can I log exceptions only?

Comment: It is logging 10 entries in Database

Answer (score 0):

Change the log level to ERROR:

```
<level value="ERROR"/>
```

Comment: In filters I am using below lines. I can not do level value error because it is at root level. I have 2 appenders(Text file appender and db appender). I am logging everything in file but want only errors in db.
       <levelMin value="INFO" />
        <levelMax value="ERROR" />